# How to move to XML configurations

Tags: java, xml

I am required to move some of our application configuration classes to XMLs. The classes mainly have enums, which are used by other classes. These enums are extensively used in our application. 
For instance, we have classes like

```
    enum ColumnType{
        type1("Type1"),type2("type2"),type3("type3")
    }
```

Also we need these types to instantiate classes.
for instance,

```
    Processor p = new StringValueProcessor(ColumnType.type1);
```

How can I move this to an XML file without changing the dependecies in my application?

Edit:
It is not mandatory to keep these enums and I don't want to compile the code against the classes created from xml. The config needs to be dynamic, that's the whole point of moving to XML, so that we can configure things in XML and there is no need of compiling and re-deploying.
My main concern is to be able to restrict instances for all column types to one and make them accessible throughout my application.

Edit: After thinking over the design for some more time, I have narrowed down to two essential requirements.
1) I would define some xml tags with some properties and I would need to convert it to object
2) I would also define some tags (the way servlets are defined in web.xml) and I would need to initialise the corresponding class
3) I would further define some mapping tags which will map the objects created in step 1) to instances initialised in step 2). This should be converted to java HashMap, where there can be only one instance of objects defined in step 1) but there will be a new instance of objects defined in step 2) for each mapping.
Is there a framework which can provide this functionality out-of-the-box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the XML files to generate the enums.  This has to be done at compile/build time, or you cannot use them in your code like the second example (as they don't exist at compile time)

Why do you want to migrate the enums to XML?

Comment: our goal is to make application flexible enough to be configurable without re-compiling and deployment. What could be the workaround if compiling is not an option? Perhaps we can create instances of these types and then pass them to classes like StringValueProcessor?

Comment: You can do this dynamically, however the problem is you cannot refer to them in code which is compiled (because they don't exist at compile time) And code which uses these "enums" must also be compiled dynamically.

Comment: I don't have to keep them as enums. I can make these as regular classes but I am unable to understand how I can then initialize my classes using these instances and how should I keep only one instance of each column type and share them throughout my app.

Comment: You can make them only one instance by creating them as `public static final` variables and making the constructor `private`  However, if the code is generated I don't see why you wouldn't use `enum`s as they are generally simpler.

Comment: I can't have the generated code, that defeats the whole purpose of moving to XMLs beacause generated code will be required to be compiled and redeployed. I need to create type instances, which would be used at other places. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: You can generate the code at runtime and compile it with the Compiler API. The problem is you can't use at compile time anything which is only available at runtime.

Comment: I am marking this as accepted answer bcz it's closest to my original question. But since then, I have figured out that we can work without enums and thus have rephrased my question. Please see if you know of a framework which can do the things I require out-of-the-box, I have mentioned my requirements as an Edit to my original question. I am currently exploring apache digester

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer your looking for is to use [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/).  It lets you turn XML into POJOs and vice-versa.  It even has some functionality for using enums.  All you have to do is add some annotations to your java and you can convert to and from XML.

By using annotations, you won't affect any existing functionality.